# Conflicting Parameter Types for Scroll View Delegate

Tags: ios, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have the function:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale
```

The declaration is copied from the documentation. However, I am getting a "convicting parameter types

`" warning 'CGFLoat' (aka double)  vs 'float'.`

Changing the float to a `CGFloat` does not make the warning go away. How do I fix?

Comment: Try changing `float` to `CGFloat` and then compiling.  Sometimes it glitches like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The (current) online documentation is actually wrong (or not up-to-date).
It is documented in the [iOS 7.0 API Diffs](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/releasenotes/General/iOS70APIDiffs/index.html)
that the declaration of the delegate method has changed to

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
                  withView:(UIView *)view
                   atScale:(CGFloat)scale; // <-- "CGFloat" instead of "float"
```

On 64-bit architectures (such as arm64), `CGFloat` is defined as a `double` and
therefore different from a `float`.