# Xcode warning with 64-bit devices

Tags: ios, xcode

I am getting a warning when I run an app on 64-bit iOS simulator or devices

The warning is:

Conflicting parameter types in implementation of 'scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:': 'CGFloat' (aka 'double') vs 'float'

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {
```

If I switch float to double

I get the error:

Conflicting parameter types in implementation of 'scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:': 'CGFloat' (aka 'double') vs 'float'

So how is it that I can remove the error for both 32-bit and 64-bit devices?

Comment: Use CGFloat as the type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conflicting Parameter Types for Scroll View Delegate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093752/conflicting-parameter-types-for-scroll-view-delegate)